# Can I make a texture from specific fragment?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments, opengl-es, render-to-texture

I want to make a texture from fragment(with FragmentActivity)'s content.
I use OpenGL ES2.0.

I try to render fragment to frame buffer by binding frame buffer in onCreate().
I think that if it is possible, the fragment won't be displayed. However, it doesn't work. It was displayed.

I have no idea to do this, now.
How can I do this?

Comment: I don't know specifically about fragments, but I did this for views a long time ago. Assuming that this is similar: From what I remember, there was a way to override the view drawing to render it to a bitmap. I believe it might have been by overriding the `onDraw()` method, and substituting the `Canvas` with one that was tied to a bitmap. Then create an OpenGL texture from the bitmap with `GLUtils.texImage2D()`.

Comment: what is Canvas? android.graphic.Canvas? or aws.Canvas?

Comment: The argument of the `View.onDraw()` method.

Comment: How can I substitute the Canvas?

Comment: The way I remember it, I created a new Canvas backed by a Bitmap, and then passed that new Canvas to the base class implementation of `onDraw()`, instead of the one that was passed in as an argument. Or at least that's the way I would try to do it.